# Populate integers to dropdownlist using a loop

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, list, loops, populate

Can't figure out why my program wont populate my **DropDownList** using a loop.

So far I've tried these two scenarios:

```vb
'Fill in the year box from current year to 100 years ago.
'(Safe to assume no one over 100 will be signing up for site)

Dim CurYear As Integer = Date.Now.Year
Dim CurYearMinus100 As Integer = CurYear - 100
Dim Index As Integer = 0

Do While CurYear >= CurYearMinus100
    DropDownListYear.Items.Insert(Index, CurYear)
    Index += 1
    CurYear -= 1
Loop
```

I've also tried using the `.Add()` functionality instead of insert:

```vb
Dim CurYear As Integer = Date.Now.Year
Dim CurYearMinus100 As Integer = CurYear - 100

Do While CurYear >= CurYearMinus100
    DropDownListYear.Items.Add(Index)
    CurYear -= 1
Loop
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure why you need `Index`, but this code will work:

```vb
Dim CurYear As Integer = Date.Now.Year
Dim CurYearMinus100 As Integer = CurYear - 100

Do While CurYear >= CurYearMinus100
    DropDownListYear.Items.Add(New ListItem(CurYear.ToString(), CurYear.ToString()))
    CurYear -= 1
Loop
```

Answer (score 1):

I personally am a fan of the **[For...Next](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5z06z1kb.aspx)** statement with a decrementing **Step** argument.

> Optional. Numeric expression. The amount by which counter is
>   incremented each time through the loop.

Your example would be:

```vb
Dim currentYear = Date.Now.Year

For year = currentYear To currentYear - 100 Step -1

   DropDownListYear.Items.Add(New ListItem(year.ToString(), year.ToString()))

Next
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace this:

```
DropDownListYear.Items.Insert(Index, CurYear)
```

With:

```
DropDownListYear.Items.Insert(Index, new ListItem(CurYear.ToString(), CurYear.ToString()))
```